# PowerTransformer Producing Unexpected Result for Just One Column

Tags: python, scikit-learn, training, preprocessing, dataframe

I'm doing some preprocessing on my training data before fitting it to a model. Upon checking the results, there is one column that is returning 0 rather than 1 for the standard deviation. (all columns return a mean of 0 as expected). My code is below:

```
y = ml_df['target']
x = ml_df[['Feature1', 'Feature2',  'Feature3', 'Feature4', 'Feature5', 'Feature6', 
        'Feature7', 'Feature8', 'Feature9', 'Feature10', 'Feature11', 'Feature12']]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.55, random_state=3)
pt_hp = PowerTransformer()
x_train_gaussian = pt_hp.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_gaussian =  pt_hp.transform(x_test)
```

After running the above, this line produces the following output:

```
print(x_train_gaussian.std(axis = 0))
```

Out: [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]

This particular feature (histogram below) is not materially different than the others; is contains only positive values (no zeros that would impact PowerTransformer) and not anywhere close to near-zero variance. Does anyone have any idea why this one particular column is returning such a different standard deviation than the rest? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.[image]

Edit - added histogram of original feature.

Comment: It looks like indeed it's the `PowerTransformer`.  I'm not too familiar with these transformers, but (1) what's the value of `lambdas_` corresponding to that feature, (2) can you provide a histogram for the original feature, (3) does `method='box-cox'` suffer the same issue?

Comment: Since you say the scaler is redundant, please edit the question title to refer to `PowerTransformer` instead, and slim down you example to exclude that redundancy.

Comment: I've updated the question as suggested. I am getting a fitted lambda of -19.6 for that feature using YeoJohnson; when I try with BoxCox, it's -4.8. No idea why there's such a discrepancy between the two; I would simply fit the Transformer with BoxCox, but several of the other columns have negative values.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug, captured in [Issue14959](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14959), with a linked pull request in the works (slightly stalled now).

The easiest fix for now is just to center your data first.

Comment: Thanks a lot - would not have guessed it was due to a bug. Will do as suggested in that link and center the data prior to applying the PowerTransformer.